# Image width relative to screen resolution

Tags: css

I've just looked over this website :

http://www.morphix.si/#home

And I was wondering how can the image width could be resized to screen resolution? (or in other words : how do they arrange the CSS like that so it will look the same in every screen?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the `background-image` than here is a CSS3 solution

```
background: url(images/image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Also if you are interested for designing the layouts compatible to each and every screen, you can use @media query specific to screen resolutions, often used for responsive designs like

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  /* Styles goes here */
}
```